# Word for expressing pushing one's health limit as if overdrafting a bank account?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose Tim is working very hard and constantly pushing his limit, at the cost of his health, by often staying up late and forgetting to take breaks.  This is similar to overdrafting one's bank account, but here he is "overdrafting" his health "account". So I wonder if there is a verb or an expression that closely means "overdrafting" one's health "account"?

Thanks!

Comment: When you take an overdraft, you have withdrawn more money than you have and are in debt. The same cannot be said for health as you cannot take more than you have. So no, I don't think you will find an equivalent word.

Comment: where is my comment to zoo's original reply (now comment)?

Comment: It went away when the owner of the question deleted it. Comments are considered somewhat expendable because they are not 'necessary'.

Comment: @zooone9243: Your understanding is different from mine. "A person overdrafts his health" is understood as he overuses his body, keeping working when his body signals it cannot stand and need rest.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has mentioned yet, but the standard verb for "overdraft" is "overdrawing". "Overdrafting" will be understood but is slightly non-standard.

Comment: @Tim I tried to manually convert my answer into a comment as you had clarified your question further. The text of your original comment was "The metaphore is understood in a different way: you are using your body more than its capability, i.e. you still keep pushing limit while your body signals that it cannot take any more and it needs rest."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's the idiom ***burning the candle at both ends***, which one website<sup>1</sup> defines as:

> *To exhaust oneself or one's resources by leading a hectic or extravagant life*.

It doesn't necessarily imply health risks, but could certainly be used in that context.

---

<sup>1</sup>[thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/burning+the+candle+at+both+ends)

Answer (score 2):

**Over-exerting** is an option.

> By working hard, he is over-exerting himself.

Other words or idioms:

- to toil (struggle hard)
- to slog away
- work one's fingers to the bone
- work like a Trojan
- work one's socks off
- put oneself through the mill
- keep one's nose to the grindstone

Comment: Over-extending is a related possibility.

Answer (score 2):

A similar phrase is **on borrowed time**.

Answer (score 1):

[*Bankrupting your health*](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22bankrupting+your+health%22&oq=%22bankrupting+your+health%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.4144.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.y7lsKtCqRB0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3aef3decdcf0bcf9&biw=1366&bih=552) seems to be a phrase sometimes used when people continue to practice bad health habits that eventually catch up with them. I think it would mean that you are aware of the habits, but continue to do them.

Answer (score 1):

On can refer to "overtaxing his/her strength/health." Money is not the only thing that can be **overtaxed.**

Another word is to **overexert.**

Answer (score 0):

What about working beyond one's health capacity?

Comment: Answers do not typically end in question marks.